# Summing over a multiindex pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

Let's say I create the following dataframe with a df.set_index('Class','subclass'), bearing in mind there are multiple Classes with subclasses... A>Z.

```
Class   subclass    
  A       a           
  A       b 
  A       c 
  A       d 
  B       a            
  B       b
```

How would I count the subclasses in the Class and create a separate column named no of classes such that I can see the Class with the greatest number of subclasses? I was thinking some sort of for loop which runs through the Class letters and counts the subclass if that Class letter is still the same. However, this seems a bit counterintuitive for such a problem. Would there be a more simple approach such as a df.groupby[].count?

The desired output would be:

```
Class   subclass    No. of classes
  A       a                4    
  A       b 
  A       c 
  A       d 
  B       a                2    
  B       b
```

I have tried the level parameter as shown in [group multi-index pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18689474/group-multi-index-pandas-dataframe) but this doesn't seem to work for me

EDIT:

I did not mention that I wanted a return of the Class with the greatest number of subclasses. I achieved this with:

```
df.reset_index().groupby('Class')['subclass'].nunique().idxmax()
```

Comment: IIUC you can do `df['No. of classes'] = df.groupby('Class')['subclass'].transform('count')`

Comment: Do you need empty values in `No. of classes` ?

Comment: I wanted a return of the class with the greatest number of subclasses. After more searching I wrote the following: 'df.reset_index().groupby('Class')['subclass'].nunique().idxmax()' which worked.

Comment: @Joey - Yes, it is good solution for greatest number of sublasses. I add another one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html), but get duplicates values:

```
df['No. of classes'] = df.groupby(level='Class')['val'].transform('size')

print (df)
                val  No. of classes
Class subclass                     
A     a           1               4
      b           4               4
      c           5               4
      d           4               4
B     a           1               2
      b           2               2
```

But if need empty values:

```
df['No. of classes'] = df.groupby(level='Class')
                         .apply(lambda x: pd.Series( [len(x)] + [np.nan] * (len(x)-1)))
                         .values
print (df)
                val  No. of classes
Class subclass                     
A     a           1             4.0
      b           4             NaN
      c           5             NaN
      d           4             NaN
B     a           1             2.0
      b           2             NaN
```

Another solution for get `Class` with greatest number is:

```
df = df.groupby(level=['Class'])
       .apply(lambda x: x.index.get_level_values('subclass').nunique())
       .idxmax()
print (df)
A
```

Comment: If say I wanted to find the sum of the top 3 vals in each Class and return the top 3 Classes with the highest sum, could I use a similar expression? say 'df.groupby('Class')['val'].nlargest(3)' to sort the top 3 vals in each Class and then apply another expression to sum the top 3 and sort?

Comment: Do you think `df.groupby('Class')['val'].apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(3).sum())` ?

Comment: And then if need top add `idxmax()` like `df.groupby('Class')['val'].apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(3).sum()).idxmax()`

Comment: Or if need top `3` use `nlargest` again `df.groupby('Class')['val'].apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(3).sum()).nlargest(3)`

Comment: exactly what I needed. Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad can help you.

Comment: BTW, how would i return just the index values of the Classes with the highest sum(vals) as strings? so the output would be ('A','B','C'). I find it hard to add all this into the group by function.

is there something like .idxmax(top3)?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `transform` to add an aggregated calculation back to the original df as a new column:

```
In [165]:
df['No. of classes'] = df.groupby('Class')['subclass'].transform('count')
df

Out[165]:
  Class subclass  No. of classes
0     A        a               4
1     A        b               4
2     A        c               4
3     A        d               4
4     B        a               2
5     B        b               2
```